# UserDefault values are missing

Tags: swift3, userdefaults

I want to save some values in `UserDefaults`. And I am using this code to save

```
func SaveSettings(){
    let def = UserDefaults.standard
    def.set("test", forKey: "Value1")
    def.set(myString, forKey: "Value2") //value: test1
    def.set(myInt, forKey: "Value3")    //value: 25
    def.set(myInt64, forKey: "Value4")  //value: 103254
    def.synchronize() //I've tried to remove this line
}
```

After saving I use this code to control if my values are saved in `UserDefaults` or not

```
 for (key, value) in UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation() {
      print("\(key) = \(value) \n")
 }
```

And see this result

```
{
   Value1 = test
   Value2 = test1
   Value3 = 25
   Value4 = 103254
}
```

There isn't any problem untill now. But After I restart the app and look at the values in `UserDefaults` I see this result

```
{
   Value1 = test
   Value2 =
}
```

As you see `Value3`ad `Value4` are missing. However `Value2` and `Value1` stays. but `Value2`'s value is missing

Comment: `let def = UserDefaults.standart` does not compile, which means that this cannot be your real code.

Comment: Sorry. It would be `standard`

Comment: Have you called `.removeObject(forKey:)` anywhere in your code?

Comment: No. I haven't called

Comment: i you restart the app then which is first viewcontroller called see there is any global variable declare or any value file in viewdidload or any other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem.

`SaveSettings()` func have called when `myInt` and `myInt64`'s values are `nil` and `myString`'s value is empty. Somehow `Value3` and `Value4` are deleted here. I guess this happen becaues of their value is `nil`. But I am not sure this is exact reason.

Comment: Yes. This was the reason. Setting value for any key in `UserDefaults` removes the corresponding data. And storing any `Optional` type in `UserDefaults` is a bad practice too. Unwrap your `Optional` before saving them to `UserDefaults`.

Answer (score 0):

When you run your app, string value which u have set in the Value1 will get saved, but the string objects are not getting any values when the app initially runs. So you need to check `myInt`, `myString`, `myInt64` are not getting nil before saving into `UserDefaults.standard`.